# Determining a bivariate probability

Tags: probability, statistics

So, I was practicing some homework problems, but I'm unsure what this question is asking:

[image: Question]

Do I need to determine `P(Y = 0)`, `P(Y = 1)`, `P(Y = 4)`, `P(Y = 9)`, `P(Y = 16)`?

If so, wouldn't `P(Y = 4)`, `P(Y = 9)` and `P(Y = 16)` be `0`?

Any clarification or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: We want the probability that $X=0$ **and** $Y=0$, plus the probability that $X=1$ **and** $Y=1$. Both the required probabilities can be read off from the table. Indeed $Y$ "can't" be $4$ or $9$ or $16$.

Comment: I can't understand why we want f_XY(0,0) and f_XY(1,1), and not just f_Y(0) and f_Y(1)?

Comment: Because if for example we have $Y=0$ and $X=3$, then $Y=X^2$ is not true.

Comment: You are welcome.